# Calculation of Percentage in Qlik

Tags: aggregate, percentage, qlikview, qliksense

My Data is in this format

```
name number result
A 27 30
B 35 60
C 41 60
D 67 90
E 10 30
F 29 30
G 40 60
H 90 90
I 120 120
J 23 30
K 4 30
L 56 60
M 7 30
N 124 Beyond
```

I want a pivot wherein I can calculate the percentage of (Count of 30/Total     Count).

```
For e.g. in above example
Count of 30 = 6
Total Count = 14
```

I want this as a percentage in this format

```
30 - 6/14
60 - 4/14
90 - 2/14
120 - 1/14
Beyond - 1/14

Where 14 = Sum of all above values. This needs to be done in Qlik
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in a chart use the result as the dimension and this as the expression

`count(name)&'/'&count(total name)`

it will give you this

[image: Chart]

Answer (score -1):

In Qlikview, on a chart this can be done on the expression, choose the relative option and it will show in %

[image]

Comment: Agreed that will provide the absolute answer but the question is specific about wanting the answer in the format x/y which this option can not do

Comment: I would suggest updating your question to not include the word percentage as this misled me.